# Sending a html form with hidden elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Today I came across a weird behaviour. I have made an html form using Bootstrap for users to subscribe. You can subscribe multiple users at once, but to see the second and the third user's input fields, you have to toggle a select button first (https://prnt.sc/t96lxt). The issue is that I can not send the form for only 1 or 2 users, because some fields of the hidden parts are set to be required.

So, my question is, how can a send a form with hidden parts that contain required fields?

My form is to be found at http://debosvrienden.alfapre.be/nl/inschrijving

Comment: Please add your code here, in your question.  See [mre].

Comment: Add/remove the `required` attribute when you show/hide the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this using javascript

```
const checkBox = document.querySelector("YOUR_CHECKBOX");

checkBox.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    document.querySelector(".hidden-input-field-1").setAttribute("required", true);
    document.querySelector(".hidden-input-field-2").setAttribute("required", true);
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".hidden-input-field-1").setAttribute("required", false);
    document.querySelector(".hidden-input-field-2").setAttribute("required", false);
  }
});
```

Obviously, you would have to use your own selectors.
Here, you are just getting a reference to your checkbox, and once it changes, you are changing the required attribute of the inputs.